# Можно ли привязать числовые значения к точкам на графике Seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

На картинке - кластеризация к средних. Центроиды обозначают точку депо, из которого выезжает объект, маленькие точки - места, в которые объект должен попасть (нужно найти самое оптимальное решение, потому что попасть он может далеко не во все).

Заказчик хочет привязать к графику данные о координатах точек и центроидов, а потом вывести списком какие точки относятся к определенному центроиду.

При этом координаты центроидов выглядят вот так (эту информацию тоже надо как-то показать на графике:

```
dep1 = {'lat': 56.730835, 'lng': 61.358041}
```

[image]

Я прочитала кучу документации, но так и не поняла, возможно ли сделать эту задачу. Буду очень рада, если подскажете, в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Мне кажется, тут нужно больше информации. Как вы строите эту кластеризацию? Как выглядят остальные ваши данные?

Comment: График построен через seaborn, кластеризация к средних - достаточно классический метод. Часть данных в словарях, как прикладывала выше, часть - в матрице, но это не сильно отличается от того, если бы они были в списках или кортежах.

Comment: Ну у вас же цвет кластеров на картинке показан, значит кластеры, к которым относятся точки, определились. Надо только вывести это всё списками, я правильно понимаю? Чтобы вам помогли, нужно добавить в вопрос код и данные в воспроизводимом виде. Хотя может быть вы с этой задачей уже сами разобрались за это время.